Separate a column in different columns depending on a label
I have a dataset in which one of the columns have a string as value.
The string has this kind of aspect:
F: whatever; F: whatever; P: whatever; P: whatever; C:whatever; C: whatever;
I want to separate that column in 3 columns: one for F, another one for P and another one for C, when there is more than one F (or P or C) I need a different row for each one (remaining the rest of columns the same).
How could I do this?
Thank you in advance!
Example:
Name Value GOs
Ab1 1000 "F: f1; F: f2; P: p1"
Bb1 2000 "P: p1; F: f1"
Cb1 3000 "C: c1; F: f1"

what I want as output:
Name Value F P C
Ab1 1000 f1 p1 -
Ab1 1000 f2 p1 -
Bb1 2000 f1 p1 -
Cb1 3000 f1 - c1

I tried with
str_match(a, "F:\\s*(.*?)\\s*;") 

but it only works for the first match, I need all the matches.
df <- data.frame(Name = c("A","B","C"),Value = c(10,20,30),GOs= c("F: f1; F: f2; P: p1","P: p1; F: f1","C: c1; F: f1"))


Could you edit your question to include reproducible sample data?

“ when there is more than one F (or P or C)” you mean like this? “F: whatever, P: wherever”, same line?

I mean that I can have more than one for each line, for example: "F: Metabolic; F:transport; P: Hydrolase; P: Binding;"

Please provide some sample data, using for example dput(head(YOURDATA))

For the updated example:
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  Name = c("A", "B"),
  Value = c(10, 20),
  GOs = c("C:e; F:n; F:D; F:D; P:D; P:h", "F:t; F:v; F:l; F:m; P:o")
)

df |> 
  separate_longer_delim(GOs, delim = ";") |> 
  separate_wider_delim(GOs, delim = ":", names_sep = ":") |> 
  mutate(across(everything(), str_squish), row = row_number()) |> 
  pivot_wider(names_from = `GOs:1`, values_from = `GOs:2`, values_fn = list) |> 
  unnest(c("C", "F", "P"))
#> # A tibble: 11 × 6
#>    Name  Value   row C     F     P    
#>    <chr> <chr> <int> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#>  1 A     10        1 e     <NA>  <NA> 
#>  2 A     10        2 <NA>  n     <NA> 
#>  3 A     10        3 <NA>  D     <NA> 
#>  4 A     10        4 <NA>  D     <NA> 
#>  5 A     10        5 <NA>  <NA>  D    
#>  6 A     10        6 <NA>  <NA>  h    
#>  7 B     20        7 <NA>  t     <NA> 
#>  8 B     20        8 <NA>  v     <NA> 
#>  9 B     20        9 <NA>  l     <NA> 
#> 10 B     20       10 <NA>  m     <NA> 
#> 11 B     20       11 <NA>  <NA>  o

Created on 2024-04-18 with reprex v2.1.0

When there is more than 1 repeated category this error appears: Error in unnest(): ! In row 1, can't recycle input of size 3 to size 2. for example with I obtained this error with this dataset:  df <- data.frame( Name = c("A","B"), Value = c(10,20), GOs= c("C:e; F:n; F:D; F:D; P:D; P:h","F:t; F:v; F:l; F:m; P:o") )

I've adjusted it for the updated example. I needed to add a row number. You could delete that with |> select(-row) if needed.

EDITED:
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  separate_rows(GOs, sep = "; ") %>%
  extract(GOs,
          into = c("X","content"),
          regex = "(.)\\W+(.+)") %>%
  pivot_wider(
              names_from = X, values_from = content,
              # add to suppress warning:
              values_fn = list) %>%
  unnest(c("F", "P", "C"))
# A tibble: 4 × 5
  Name  Value F     P     C    
  <chr> <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 A        10 f1    p1    NA   
2 A        10 f2    p1    NA   
3 B        20 f1    p1    NA   
4 C        30 f1    NA    c1  

Data:
df <- data.frame(Name = c("A","B","C"),
                 Value = c(10,20,30),
                 GOs= c("F: f1; F: f2; P: p1","P: p1; F: f1","C: c1; F: f1"))

EDIT 2:
Alternatively, consider this output structure:
df %>%
  separate_rows(GOs, sep = "; ") %>%
  extract(GOs,
          into = c("X","content"),
          regex = "(.)\\W+(.+)") %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = X, values_from = content, values_fn = toString)
# A tibble: 3 × 5
  Name  Value F      P     C    
  <chr> <dbl> <chr>  <chr> <chr>
1 A        10 f1, f2 p1    NA   
2 B        20 f1     p1    NA   
3 C        30 f1     NA    c1 


It solve the problem of  split the column, but the other problem is that in a single row, it can be more than one F, for example: "F: value 1; F: value 2" and I need them to be in different rows.

Please provide some sample data, using for example dput(head(YOURDATA))

When there is more than 1 repeated category this error appears: Error in unnest(): ! In row 1, can't recycle input of size 3 to size 2. for example with I obtained this error with this dataset: df <- data.frame( Name = c("A","B"), Value = c(10,20), GOs= c("C:e; F:n; F:D; F:D; P:D; P:h","F:t; F:v; F:l; F:m; P:o") )

See new solution in edit, which is applicable to both data samples

To avoid reshaping, which might be slow, you could first extract colnames and values using gregexpr/regmatches. With the unique colnames make an array with no rows and merge it to the list elements, next merge all together, finally cbind.
> r <- lapply(c(cn='(.)(?=\\:)', v='(?<=\\:\\s)(.\\d)'), \(x) 
+             regmatches(df$GOs, gregexpr(x, df$GOs, perl=TRUE)))
> u <- unique(unlist(r$cn))
> a <- array(dim=c(0, length(u)), dimnames=list(NULL, u))
> Map(cbind, Name=df$Name, Value=df$Value, 
+     Map(\(x, y) split(x, y), r$v, r$cn) |>
+       lapply(do.call, what='data.frame') |> 
+       lapply(merge, a, all=TRUE)) |> 
+   Reduce(f=rbind)
  Name Value  F    P    C
1  Ab1  1000 f1   p1 <NA>
2  Ab1  1000 f2   p1 <NA>
3  Bb1  2000 f1   p1 <NA>
4  Cb1  3000 f1 <NA>   c1


Data:
> dput(df)
structure(list(Name = c("Ab1", "Bb1", "Cb1"), Value = c(1000L, 
2000L, 3000L), GOs = c("F: f1; F: f2; P: p1", "P: p1; F: f1", 
"C: c1; F: f1")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L
))

